# How to inherit same name variables from multiple parent classes?

Tags: python, inheritance, method-resolution-order

I ran into some problems regarding python's multiple inheritance.

```
class TestFather(object):
    fathers = {}
    path = "/C"

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestFather, self).__init__()
        # self.fathers = file_to_dict(self.path)


class TestMother(object):
    mothers = {}
    path = "/D"

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestMother, self).__init__()
        # self.mothers = file_to_dict(self.path)


class TestChild(TestFather, TestMother):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestChild, self).__init__()


t = TestChild()
help(t)
```

The variable path will store the file directory for mothers and fathers. When I print out both the fathers and mothers dictionaries, I notice that mothers dictionary somehow takes all the information from fathers. After reading through Guido's blog on MRO http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html and watching Raymond Hettinger's 2015 PyCon video super is super, I realize that TestChild class only inherit the path variable from TestFather, and completely ignores the path variable from TestMother.

**My Question is, is there a way for TestChild to use its two parents' respective path instead of only taking the one with higher MRO.** I know changing the variable names will do the trick but as Raymond said, there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

TestChild cannot *implicitly* inherit both, because of the obvious name collision: TestChild.path cannot have two values simultaneously.  Since you haven't described the semantics you want for TestChild accessing both values, I'm not sure what you truly need for a solution.

However, you *can* expand on the **__init__** function, storing the names within TestChild however you like -- perhaps a list of two strings?